# .NET: Can C#/C++CLI overload/hook IUnknown?

Tags: c#, .net, com, c++-cli

I have been playing with COM/NET for a while now, and I am curious if the common language runtime allows you to hook/override IUnknown::QueryInterface so that when QueryInterface is called with a specific IID, it will work differently than default.

One way of accomplishing this is by

1. creating a project DummyGreeter with Greeter.vb as comvisible but not exported for COM interop in any language.
2. create a project DummyWrapper with main.cpp, DummyWrapper.def(exporting DllGetClassObject, DllCanUnloadNow), with DllGetClassObject exposing a pure C++ class derived from IClassFactory, that creates an instance of pure C++ class derived from IDispatch that internally creates my DummyGreeter and whenever QueryInterface is called on it, it checks for my special IID, and if it is, set ppv to a my special value, and otherwise, call the DummyGreeter's queryinterface.

I was wondering if there was a way to do something like this directly via

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[ComVisible(true), Guid("93FA9DCA-45C0-492D-8067-15B580B84135")]
public class Greeter
{
    public void Greet() {
        Console.WriteLine("hi");
    }

    public void QueryInterface(Guid id, ref object returnValue) {
        if (id == new Guid("97D87EC0-286B-4A5F-83E6-7ACC12579E0B")) {
            returnValue = "yep";
            return;
        }

        this.DefaultQueryInterface(id, returnValue);
    }
}
```

is something like this possible, or do you always need a COM wrapper to do something like this. I can imagine it being impossible because ideally, .NET objects should not know about COM so that they can work in environments where there is no COM, but at the same time, on a windows platform, it does generate COM code when you make things COMVisible, so I imagine there should be a way to hook the intermediate QueryInteface calls in either C# or at least through C++CLI.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.icustomqueryinterface(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted! thanks!

Comment: also, is this possible for the classfactory of the object? this was only for the object itself.

Comment: See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45192476/5770014)